# Validation for date picker in Angular2

Tags: angular, validation, datepicker, directive

I am using a custom directive for date picker. Here is the template:

```
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" id="tbxDate"
         pattern="\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}"
         class="form-control" (change)="changeValue($event)"
         (blur)="onTouchedCallback()"/>
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn" (click)="show()">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div id="calendar-popup" class="calendar-popup"
          [style.display]="panelVisible ? 'block' : 'none'" 
          [style.width]="width">
          <bootflat-date-picker id="btf" [options]="myDatePickerOptions" 
            (dateChanged)="selectDate($event)" [(selDate)]="selectionDate">
            </bootflat-date-picker>
    </div>
```

But the pattern validation is not working. It is taking alphanumeric as well. I want to restrict to take only MM/DD/YY

Comment: why don't you use the input type as `date`

Comment: I tried that ,but then the pop-up calendar is of no use as inbuild date template is appearing .

Comment: so you can make the input as read only and restrict only through the popup right

Comment: yes but the requirement is such that both way it able to take input. Is there any way to add pattern field to restrict the input coz the one I added is not parsed by angular

Comment: can you create a plunker ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/8JKEEYIhpADMnUqpImhG?p=preview).

Updated the Regrex

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" id="tbxDate"
     pattern="/^(0?[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](19|20)?[0-9]{2})*$/"
     class="form-control" (change)="changeValue($event)"
     (blur)="onTouchedCallback()"/>
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn" (click)="show()">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
 </div>
```

The user will be able to enter any value to the field but he cannot submit the form he will be prompted for enter the required pattern.